# Experience with issues faced while upgrading from OpenLayers 4 to 6

Tags: openlayers, upgrade

We are thinking of migrating from OL 4 to 6, skipping 5. I read the [upgrade notes](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/changelog/upgrade-notes.md), but I wanted to know if someone here also jumped from v4 to v6 and their experience if they faced any major hurdles in upgrading.

Comment: If you used the version 4 full build `ol.js` you could simply substitute that and the `ol.css` with the latest versions and see if there are any issues.  Some applications may work without further changes, while heavily customised code is likely to need reworking.  The need to register proj4 after setting up definitions introduced by version 5 (`ol/proj/proj4.register(proj4);` using full build syntax) is an often needed but simple change.